# TexStudio git integration

Tags: texstudio, git

I tried to add some basic git commands to my TexStudio build step.
Unfortunately, this does not seem to be as straightforward as I thought.

As you can see in the picture, I tried adding my custom commands, but the first runs several times per second and then freezes the application.

Has someone experience with this?

Kind regards
Andi

[image: image of settings]

UPDATE:
I made git work partyl.
The date is not inserted properly, and the pdf creation process does not start at all now.

[image]

Comment: By the [texstudio user manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a), sec. 1.3, the user defined commands _must_ have name `user<num>:<name>`. So you should use command names like `user0:gitcommit`, `user1:gitpush` and `user2:git`.

Comment: And, the latest non-stable texstudio 3.0.0 alpha5 now includes an embedded terminal working on Linux (see [texstudio/pr993](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/pull/993)).

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ thanks for your answer, I got some features to work but not all.
My command ``cmd /c "git commit -am "%%date%%%-%%time:~0,8%%\""`` does include the time as it should, but the date is not included. Sometimes, instead of the date, my filename is inserted here.
Pushing works fine.
Unfortunately, this broke the whole rendering, since texstudio does not compile the pdf any more at all.

Comment: Check out https://ritm.knu.ua/general/how-to-use-git-with-texstudio/ for an alternative approach using macros